# Google Search Console crawl ReactJs website hosted as AWS Cloudfront (S3 bucket) gives 403 forbidden error on React routes

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cloudfront, google-search-console

I have hosted my reactjs website on AWS cloudfront keeping my build folder in AWS s3. s3 bucket can be accessed only from cloudfront. Google search console was able to crawl my homepage and google search also showing my homepage but not the react routes. As shown in the image, when I was trying to test live url, it is giving me 403 forbidden error. I tried making the bucket public to see if that works, but I am getting the same issue. How can I resolve this ?

[Please check this attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azIRB.png)

Comment: Resolved. On the Cloudfront error page the HTTP response code was 403 by mistake. Changed to 200